# Android: How to allow a "dynamicly created" button (in JavaScript) to work from within a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

When I open a certain activity on my `Android` app, it creates a `WebView` that loads an `HTML` page (which resides on the server). The `HTML` page has a `JavaScript` code inside it.

In the `JavaScript`, I have the following lines to show a "file-select" form:

```
var fileinput = document.createElement('input');
fileinput.type = 'file';
```

It works fine on `Chrome` and I can browse to my file before sending. But, on my `Android` app, when I tap on `Choose file` button (on the `WebView`) nothing happen.

Again when I receive the selected file in another `Chrome`, I use the following code to download (i.e: to save) the transfered file:

```
var href = document.createElement('a');
href.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
href.download = metadata.name;
href.appendChild(document.createTextNode('download'));
item.appendChild(href)
```

But again it doesn't work on `Android` although it works fine on `Chrome`.

My question is how to let these button (which are created dynamicly) to work from within the `WebView` in `Android`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that webview doesn't provide default implementation for file picker.

You should then create a javascriptInterface for your webview and define methods for choosing file to upload and where to download. Then call those methods from your html code.